# How long does java thread switch take?

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I'm learning reactive programming techniques, with async I/O etc, and I just can't find decent authoritative comparative data about the benefits of not switching threads.

Apparently switching threads is "expensive" compared to computations. But what scale are we talking on?

The essential question is "How many processor cycles/instructions does it take to switch a java thread?" (I'm expecting a range)

Is it affected by OS?
I presume it's affected by number of threads, which is why async IO is so much better than blocking - the more threads, the further away the context has to be stored (presumably even out of the cache into main memory).

*I've seen [Approximate timings for various operations](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) which although it's (way) out of date, is probably still useful for relating processor cycles (network would likely take more "instructions", SSD disk probably less).*

*I understand that reactive applications enable web apps to go from 1000's to 10,000's requests per second (per server), but that's hard to tell too - comments welcome*

**NOTE** - I know this is a bit of a vague, useless, fluffy question at the moment because I have little idea on the inputs that would affect the speed of a context switch. Perhaps statistical answers would help - as an example I'd guess >=60% of threads would take between  100-10000 processor cycles to switch.

Comment: y not make a measurement yourself, and share it with us? it will be useful!

Comment: Because benchmarking is fraught with difficulties. Even though I know that if I don't use [Google caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) I'm going to mess it up completely, I would think thread switching is very hard to specify. I'm looking for _typical_ values of applications (primarly web I guess) which is not easy to set up. To benchmark usefully, I would need to know the dimensions that affect performance, and I can only guess at # of local references, # of registers, cache size, thread count, locks, shared variables etc.

Answer (score 3):

Thread switching is done by the OS, so Java has little to do with it. Also, on linux at least, but I presume also many other operating systems, the scheduling cost does not depend on the number of threads. Linux has been using an [O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O(1)_scheduler) scheduler since version 2.6.

The thread switch overhead on Linux is [some 1.2 µs](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/#id10) (article from 2018). Unfortunately the article doesn't list the clock speed at which that was measured, but the overhead should be some 1000-2000 clock cycles or thereabout. On a given machine and OS the thread switching overhead should be more or less constant, not a wide range.

Apart from this direct switching cost there's also the cost of changing workload: the new thread is most likely using a different set of instructions and data, which need to be loaded into the cache, but this cost doesn't differ between a thread switch or an asynchronous programming 'context switch'. And for completeness, switching to an entirely different process has the additional overhead of changing the memory address space, which is also significant.

By comparison, the switching overhead between goroutines in the Go programming language (which uses userspace threads which are very similar to asynchronous programming techniques) was around 170 ns, so one seventh of a linux thread switch.

Whether that is significant for you depends on your use case of course. But for most tasks, the time you spend doing computation will be far more than the context switching overhead. Unless you have many threads that do an absolutely tiny amount of work before switching.

Threading overhead has improved a lot since the early 2000s, and according to the linked article running 10,000 threads in production shouldn't be a problem on a recent server with a lot of memory. General claims of thread switching being slow are often based on yesteryears computers, so take those with a grain of salt.

One remaining fundamental advantage of asynchronous programming is that the userspace scheduler has more knowledge about the tasks, and so can in principle make smarter scheduling decisions. It also doesn't have to deal with processes from different users doing wildly different things that still need to be scheduled fairly. But even that can be worked around, and with the right kernel extensions [these Google engineers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXuZi9aeGTw) were able to reduce the thread switching overhead to the same range as goroutine switches (200 ns).

Answer (score 1):

Rugal has a point. In modern architectures theoretical turn-around times are usually far off from actual measurements because the hardware, as well as the software have become so much more complex. It also inherently depends on your application. Many web-applications for example are I/O-bound where the context switch time matters a lot less.

Also note that [context switching](http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching) (what you refer to as thread switching) is an OS thing and not a Java thing. There is no guarantee as to how "heavy" a context switch in your OS is. It used to take tens if not hundreds of thousands of CPU cycles to do a [kernel-level switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Models), but there are also [user-level switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Models), as well as experimental systems, where even kernel-level switches can take only a few hundred cycles.

Comment: That's a good start! I'm specifically using "java thread" for it's terminology since that's the platform I'm on. I understand it's (historically) faster than process switching, but does it completely equate to a context switch? It seems to me that your second paragraph says that "java thread context switch" is indeed a good restriction instead of "general context switch"

Comment: @Stephen Java simply offers a high level API to the low-level system threads. If you look at JVM source code, you will most probably find that the Thread class simply calls the underlying [sys calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). That is [pthreads on *nix](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html) and its [corresponding counter part on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Ah yes - that's terminology I recognize (from years back ;))